# why fetch_add uses lock prefix while fetch_and uses cmpxchg in boost atomics

Tags: c++, assembly, boost, x86, atomic

I noticed that in boost::atomics library x86 implementation (one, which does not use compiler intrinsics) of `fetch_add` uses `add` instruction with `lock` prefix:

```
static BOOST_FORCEINLINE storage_type fetch_add(storage_type volatile& storage, storage_type v, memory_order) BOOST_NOEXCEPT
{
    __asm__ __volatile__
    (
        "lock; xaddw %0, %1"
        : "+q" (v), "+m" (storage)
        :
        : BOOST_ATOMIC_DETAIL_ASM_CLOBBER_CC_COMMA "memory"
    );
    return v;
}
```

while `fetch_and`, `fetch_or` and `fetch_xor` are implemented through CAS instruction:

```
#define BOOST_ATOMIC_DETAIL_CAS_LOOP(op, argument, result)\
    __asm__ __volatile__\
    (\
        "xor %%" BOOST_ATOMIC_DETAIL_TEMP_CAS_REGISTER ", %%" BOOST_ATOMIC_DETAIL_TEMP_CAS_REGISTER "\n\t"\
        ".align 16\n\t"\
        "1: movw %[arg], %%dx\n\t"\
        op " %%ax, %%dx\n\t"\
        "lock; cmpxchgw %%dx, %[storage]\n\t"\
        "jne 1b"\
        : [res] "+a" (result), [storage] "+m" (storage)\
        : [arg] "q" (argument)\
        : BOOST_ATOMIC_DETAIL_ASM_CLOBBER_CC_COMMA BOOST_ATOMIC_DETAIL_TEMP_CAS_REGISTER, "memory"\
    )

static BOOST_FORCEINLINE storage_type fetch_and(storage_type volatile& storage, storage_type v, memory_order) BOOST_NOEXCEPT
{
    storage_type res = storage;
    BOOST_ATOMIC_DETAIL_CAS_LOOP("andw", v, res);
    return res;
}
```

Any ideas why is that so? Is this because you cannot use lock prefix with bitwise operations (not true, as far as I know)?

Comment: It isn't `add` it's `xadd`, which specifically gives you the original value. There is no `xand` and such for bitwise ops. If you don't need the original value, you can use `lock and`, yes.

Comment: I don't see how you could use that. You can't read back the value after the operation since it may change by that time, so you can't get back the original value.

Comment: Jester, now I see it. But why do we want to use the exchange version of `add`? Is it because exchange versions of instructions together with `lock` provide additional reordering guarantees?

Comment: You use `xadd` because it's simple and doesn't involve looping.

Comment: I mean why not use just `add`.

Comment: `add` doesn't return the original value, and these functions have to (that's why they are called `fetch`).

Comment: It's clear now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As Jester points out, `fetch_add` uses `xadd` instruction to return the value immediately preceding effects of the function. There is no `xand` or `xor` instructions, so CAS is used.